# Rails send strong parameter and update 2 tables at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I am new in Rails, any advises, tips would be appreciated.

rails : '4.2.5'

I have 2 tables as below.
Shop(Master table)
Shop_detail(Detail table)
There is a relation between 2 tables.

**What I want to do**

Send user input values to controllers via AJAX.
Values are like, shop_name, item_image, price, etc.

In the controller, I want to create 2 tables as below.
Shop(Master table) -> create a new record with shop_name.

Shop_detail(detail table) -> create a new record with item_image, price and shop_id which is obtained from Shop(Master table).

I want to put strong parameter as below.

```
def post_master_params <- this is for master table.
    params.permit(:shop_name)
end
def post_detail_params
    params.permit(:item_image, :price)
end

@shop = Shop.new(post_master_params)
@shop.save

@shop_detail = Shop_detail.new(post_detail_params)
@shop_detail.shop_id = @shop.id
@shop_detail.save
```

as a result, I got an error below.

> Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 83ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
>   ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):

Comment: Can you show your complete controller code?

Comment: Also show your model code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one go, but assure you have the **has_many** relation between master and child table and assure your child table has **belongs_to** to master:

```
def post_detail_params
    params.permit(:shop_name, shop_details: [:item_image, :price] )
end


post = Shop.build(post_detail_params)
post.save
```

**Model relationship:**

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many: shop_details
end

class ShopDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to: shop
end
```

Answer (score 0):

for Shop  you should use like this:

```
post_detail_params.except(:shop_details)
```

and for `ShopDetail`  table you should use:

```
post_detail_params[:shop_details]
```